# Pairwise lookup of column - R

Tags: r

I want to check whether two values in different columns but same row exist within the same column in separate data frame.

df1 looks like this:

```
Target    Acquirer  Merger date 
1         2         3/1/1990 
4         3         5/2/1991
5         6         6/8/1992
```

df2 looks like this:

```
Investor  Stock     Date        
A         1         1/1/1990
A         1         2/1/1990     
A         2         3/1/1990     
A         2         4/1/1990     
A         2         5/1/1990     
A         2         6/1/1990     
A         2         7/1/1990     
B         1         1/1/1990
B         1         2/1/1990
B         1         3/1/1990
B         1         4/1/1990
C         2         4/2/1991
C         2         5/2/1991
C         2         6/2/1991
C         2         7/2/1991
C         2         8/2/1991
```

I want to check whether the same pair of stocks (from df1, e.g. 1 and 2) are present in the same portfolio for an investor (df2). Ideally what I'm looking for is to say that target was present on the day before merger date in df1, and acquirer on any day on or post merger date.

The output I'm looking to achieve is a dummy variable in df2 next to the acquirer stock (on and after merger date) if conditions are satisfied.

Expected output:

```
Investor  Stock     Date         dummy
A         1         1/1/1990
A         1         2/1/1990     
A         2         3/1/1990     1
A         2         4/1/1990     1
A         2         5/1/1990     1
A         2         6/1/1990     1
A         2         7/1/1990     1
B         1         1/1/1990
B         1         2/1/1990
B         1         3/1/1990
B         1         4/1/1990
C         2         4/2/1991
C         2         5/2/1991
C         2         6/2/1991
C         2         7/2/1991
C         2         8/2/1991
```

I've read that dplyr can tackle this, but I've not been able to figure out how to code this exactly.

--

*Second question:*
Is it possible to also do the above check but limit the dummy to not go beyond 12 months of the date stated in df1?

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: Hope the edit now clarifies what output I'm looking for, @akrun